# Mongoose query by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to query mongoDB with document structure like this:

```
var ExampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    validUntil: Date,
    name: String
});
```

and need it to return only valid documents, i.e. where validUntil is greater than current time. This doesn't work, mongoose returns all documents:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
Example.find({ '$where': 'validUntil'>n })
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `$gte` like this :

```
Example.find({
    validUntil: {
        $gte: new Date(2016,09,30)
    }
})
```

Comment: @chovy `Date.now()` returns a number and not a Date object. If you want to compare with the current Date, then simply use `new Date()`.

Comment: @robere2 when using `new Date()` it still throws me error for casting.

Answer (score 12):

If find in today, using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

```
// start today
var start = moment().startOf('day');
// end today
var end = moment(today).endOf('day');

Example.find({ validUntil: { '$gte': start, '$lte': end })
```

Answer (score 3):

get all created account today:

```
  let start = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),1,0,0);

  let end = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()+1,0,59,59);

  let query = {createdAt: {$gte: start, $lt: end} };

  Account
  .find(query)
  .exec((err, accounts) => console.log(account) )
```