# How to get number of registered users each month with MongoDB query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve the total number of users registered each month grouping them by year and month they registered in MongoDB
My user model looks like this

```
email: String,
  
  gender: String,
  
  password: {
    hash: {
      type: String,
      // required: true
    },
    salt: {
      type: String,
      // required: true
    },
    reset: {
      id: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
      code: {
        type: String,
        default: "",
      },
    },
  },
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String,
    username: String,
  },
  date: {
    registered: {
      type: Date,
    }
  }
```

The date parameter is an ISO string

the query that I tried is this

```
var today = new Date();


            data.newUsersEachMonth=await AccountModel.aggregate([
                { "$match": {
                    "date": {"date.registered": { "$lt": today.toISOString() }}
                    }},
                { "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                        },
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }}
            ])
```

But it returns an empty array How can i solve this?

**UPDATE**

As suggested i tried these two queries

```
                { "$match": {
                    "date.registered": { "$lt": today.toISOString() }
                    }},
                { "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "year": { "$year": "$date.registered" },
                            "month": { "$month": "$date.registered" },
                        },
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }}
            ])
```

and

````
data.newUsersEachMonth=await AccountModel.aggregate([
                { "$match": {
                    "date.registered": { "$lt": today.toISOString() }
                    }},
                { "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
                            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
                        },
                        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }}
            ])```

Still getting an empty array
````

Comment: You dont need to match `"date": {"date.registered" ...`. See [Query on Embedded / Nested Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/index.html#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field).

Comment: @prasad_ just updated the question but still no result

Comment: Are you getting the correct documents filtered after the first match stage?

Comment: Also see: [Mongoose query by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332455/mongoose-query-by-date) _and_ [[Mongoose - Working with Dates - Querying](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation query should be like below,

```
[
  { 
      '$match': {
        'date.registered': { 
            '$lt': today.toISOString() 
        }
     }
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      'month': {
        '$month': '$date.registered'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$year': '$date.registered'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'month': '$month', 
        'year': '$year'
      }, 
      'total': {
        '$sum': 1
      }, 
      'month': {
        '$first': '$month'
      }, 
      'year': {
        '$first': '$year'
      }
    }
  }
]
```